# Method invocation failed … does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: powershell

I'm not sure why the error is appearing. I'm importing a csv file

```
$Mailboxes = import-csv C:\users.csv
Foreach ($User in $Mailboxes)
{Add-mailboxfolderpermission –identity ($user+':\calendar’) –user test@sample.com –Accessrights Editor}
```

Comment: Assuming the csv has a column named "email", it should be `($user.email + ':\calendar')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a string to a `PSCustomObject`, which is the resulting type you get when importing a CSV with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7). `op_Addition` is the method name which non-primitive types can implement when overloading the addition operator, which the error indicates that the `$user` object does not support an addition operation.

Remember that importing a CSV gives you an array of `PSCustomObject`, and each element in the collection is an object representation of a row in the CSV, not a string of the CSV row itself.

What you probably want is to add that string to a row's rolumn in that CSV. You would do this like so:

```
$user.ColumnName + ':\calendar'
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it says "An existing permission entry was found for user: test."  Does that mean it worked and that I had that user in the csv?

Comment: I think so. I'm not well versed in the Exchange cmdlets but that seems like an error/warning that could come from the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` cmdlet, if the permission was already set.

Comment: @Sm85 It means that the `test@sample.com` account already had `Editor` access to the mailbox in question